# NestJs connection to MySql: Error Unable to connect to the database

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Hello I have a problem connecting nestjs to mysql.
every time if I change the way of connection is different error.
This is one when having in conf.ts

If try with ocrmconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "root",
  "database": "famby_app",
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true
}



    [Nest] 27419   - 04/08/2020, 6:02:56 PM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)... +4032ms
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/baby-app-nest/src/user/user.entity.ts:2
import { Entity, Unique, BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[Nest] 27419   - 04/08/2020, 6:02:56 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Unexpected token { +1ms
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/baby-app-nest/src/user/user.entity.ts:2
import { Entity, Unique, BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

My config.ts

```
    import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { UserEntity } from './user/user.entity';
import { join } from 'path';
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'database_test',
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true
};
```

I try all possible way that I could find :/

Can someone help me if have the same issue like I have?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load up a ts file in node, which isn't possible. with the line `__dirname + '../**/*.entity.{js,ts}` you would be going from your `dist` back to root, and then loading anything that is `.entity.ts` and `.entity.js`. So your typescript source files are being loaded and Node can't properly parse those. You should either remove the `ts` from that glob, or filter down better to only look in your `dist` directory (or honestly, both would be the best)

Comment: Then I get this error: "[TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)... +3184ms
QueryFailedError: ER_DUP_KEYNAME: Duplicate key name 'IDX_415c35b9b3b6fe45a3b065030f'
    at new QueryFailedError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/baby-app-nest/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)"